# What does XCloseDisplay return?

Tags: xlib, xorg

I can see from various documentations that `XCloseDisplay` returns an integer, which I suspect to be an error code.

What should I do with this value? Is it an error code? If so how do I handle the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked in the source code (`lib/X11/ClDisplay.c`)

It says:

```
return 0;
```

So there's nothing you can really do with the return value.

Comment: What about if it fails? Does it return an error code? it seems like XCloseDisp returns 0 on success, docs dont clarify that, they just say that XCloseDisplay can "generate" BadGC (they dont clarify what generate means return)  docs: http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XCloseDisplay.3.html

Comment: It will always return 0 - it's hard coded, but anyway, the "official" way to handle X errors is to use XSetErrorHandler to provide an error handling function.

Comment: Oh thanks very much, im doing ctypes so this really helps me out. I just go by examples. Ill look for a XSetErrorHandler example.